# overexcited generators and motors supply reactive power

Tags: synchronous-motor

I know that an overexcited synchronous motor has a leading power factor.

But an overexcited synchronous generator has a lagging power factor.

However, as shown in the attached page it says that **overexcited** generators and motors supply reactive power to the system

My question is how an overexcited synchronous generator SUPPLY reactive power? overexcited synchronous generator means the power factor is LAGGING!

SOURCE:

Power System Analysis

John J. Grainger and William D. Stevenson

McGraw-Hill Series in Electrical and Computer Engineering

1994

ISBN 0-07-113338-0

[image]

Comment: you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: The definitions of "leading" and "lagging" may be reversed depending on whether you are looking from the load towards the generator or from the generator towards the load.

Comment: @Charles overexcited synchronous generator has a lagging power factor! How can a lagging power factor system supply reactive power?

Comment: "reactive power" is really not a good name.  It means the voltage and current are out of step by 90 degrees.  Which direction the 90 degrees is (lead vs lag) makes it look like a capacitor or inductor is across the lines.