# How are AC voltage regulation and overexcitation both accomplished in an AC synchronous motor?

Tags: voltage-regulator, synchronous-motor

Help me see what I'm misunderstanding here. I see a contradiction between the following two principles:

1. An AC voltage regulator attached to an AC synchronous motor will regulate terminal voltage. If the voltage gets off, it will adjust field excitation, which will affect armature CEMF, which will affect terminal voltage until it's back on track.
2. To achieve overexcitation, field excitation is increased, which will raise armature CEMF until its magnitude is greater than terminal voltage.

According to #1, a change in excitation affects terminal voltage. According to #2, a change in excitation must not affect terminal voltage in order for it to eventually exceed terminal voltage.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, there is a contradiction here.

I'll try to explain:

1. To increase the terminal voltage the generator either has to be disconnected or connected to a very weak grid (i.e. very few other generators in an island).
2. Over excitation refers to how much reactive power a generator delivers compared to the reactive load and other generator's reactive power supply.
   Example:

Two generators are connected to one load which draws 1000 kVAr.
If each generator are of equal size and delivers 500 kVAr each, thats fine.
If one generator is delivering 600 kVAr while the other is delivering 400 kVAr, one can say that the first generator is slightly overexcited compared to the other. However, it's still fine - just a slight imbalance.

In reality it means that generator 1 has a higher field current than nr 2, and the regulator for nr 2 detects this and reduces its field current slightly.

However, if there is a malfunction in regulator 1 which causes generator 1 to increase field current dramatically - the following will occur:

- Field current goes up for nr 1
- Reactive power delivery goes up for nr 1
- Reactive power delivery goes down for nr 1
- In a few tens or hundreds of miliseconds, nr 1 is delivering more than 1000 kVAr
- Now, nr 2 is receiving reactive power. Field current is at minimum and in most applications the protective relay will start to complain about "reactive power import" and sooner or later disconnect generator 2 depending on how much it is importing and for how long.
- When there are no other generators left to import reactive power voltage start to increase dramatically. It has already been increasing quite a bit, but now it will go really high - just waiting for an over voltage trip to occur.

This situation is much unwanted in small islands because it will cause the sick regulator do disconnect all the healthy ones before it eventually disconnect itself, creating a total black out.

EDIT: I have added a trend I once recorded when testing this scenario. Two online generators (around 10 MVA each) where the AVR/regulator for one of them gets disconnected from its sensing voltage so that it believes the voltage is zero thus panics and tries to increase field current as much as possible to compensate:

In this scenario the sick generator gets disconnected at ~380 ms, well before the healthy one is disconnected due to reactive power import. The reason for this test was to verify that the protection scheme which detects this fault is recognizing the fault.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the modeling/graph but I'm confused about how this answers my question. I'm not asking about a malfunction - I'm asking whether excitation affects terminal voltage. Additionally, I think I'm referring to overexcitation differently than you. Here's the kind of overexcitation I'm talking about: [overexcited generators and motors supply reactive power](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/573377/overexcited-generators-and-motors-supply-reactive-power), specifically the phasor diagram in the bottom of [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpU3h.png).

Comment: Excitation affects terminal voltage for a disconnected or single generator. If there are other generators present, then increasing excitation will simply try to force reactive power into them.

Comment: I agree with your first statement. However, if excitation does not affect terminal voltage when two or more generators are present, then I don’t see how reactive load sharing is accomplished. As far as I’m familiar, a voltage droop is maintained by generators’ voltage regulators, enabling reactive load sharing. See [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108394). This means the generators’ voltage regulators must be able to change their respective terminal voltage. I could be wrong here, but the only way they could accomplish this is by adjusting field excitation.